Kotlin WorkManager: Scheduling a Periodic POST API Call Every 15 Minutes with Persistence Across Reboots
I'm trying to use Kotlin's WorkManager to schedule a POST API call that runs every 15 minutes and continues to execute even after the device restarts or reboots. Here’s what I’m aiming for:
The task should make a POST API call with a JSON payload.
It should execute every 15 minutes.
The task should persist across device reboots so it continues without requiring any user interaction or app relaunch.
class ApiWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val jsonObject = JSONObject().apply {
                put("key1", "value1")
                put("key2", "value2")
            }
            val requestBody = RequestBody.create(
                "application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
                jsonObject.toString()
            )

            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://yourapiendpoint.com/yourpostendpoint")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build()

            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Result.success()
            } else {
                Result.retry()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.retry()
        }
    }
}

fun scheduleApiWorker(context: Context) {
    val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ApiWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setConstraints(
            Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        "ApiWorker",
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        workRequest
    )
}

Is this the correct way to set up a periodic WorkManager task that will run every 15 minutes, even after a system reboot?

While looking fine in theory, be aware that in practice such frequent work is considered an abuse of workmanager and will most likely end up being throttled. IIRC it'll happen within 48 hours of your last app launch.

As per this doc:
Work is persistent when it remains scheduled through app restarts and system reboots.
so, your work will be resumed automatically.
